# Error in recursive function / trying to find all subdirectories of a given directory

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I'm trying to write a function that returns all subdirectories of a given directory (recursive).

What I have so far is:

```
import System.Directory
import Control.Monad
import Data.List

getSubDirs :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
getSubDirs dir =
        getDirectoryContents dir
        >>= filterM (\x -> return $ x /= "." && x /= "..")
        >>= mapM (makeAbsolute . (\x -> dir ++ "/" ++ x))
        >>= filterM doesDirectoryExist
        >>= return . reverse

getDirTree :: [FilePath] -> IO [FilePath]
getDirTree [] = return []
getDirTree l@(x:xs) = do
        a <- getSubDirs x >>= getDirTree
        b <- getDirTree xs
        return (nub $ l ++ a ++ b)
```

Which seems to work. But there is something wrong with the recursion - I would like to get rid of the `nub` in `getDirTree`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
getDirTree l@(x:xs) = do
        -- ...
        b <- getDirTree xs
        return (nub $ l ++ a ++ b)
```

The last line adds `l` which is `x:xs` with `b`, which will contain the `l` argument in the `getDirTree xs` call, so `b` will contain `xs`. Hence `xs` is included twice (at every recursive step!).

Try `return ( x : a ++ b )` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I knew that the `l` was the problem - now I see why.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
getDirTree' :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
getDirTree' path = do
  subs <- getSubDirs path
  as <- mapM getDirTree' subs
  return $ subs ++ concat as
```

Comment: `getDirTree' = let foo phi x = pure x <|> (phi x >>= foo phi) in ala ListT foo`

Comment: Thank you @ErikR. Seeing alternative solutions helps a lot.